# css issue in table, styling not showing fully

Tags: html, css

got styled css table but for some reason the row styling is being cut off, css inspector is showing any obvious error. attached is the css and table

[image]
example of issue
    [`see codepen`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBGxLy#anon-login)

Comment: It seems to work for me. Can you be more specific about your problem? It seems a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: please post the code here.

Comment: It is required that you post a minimal example of the code that shows the problem here, not some third-party site that may change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Comment: added screen shot, cannot post code as its too big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `background` on `td` Instead of `tr` will solve your problem.

```
table.striped tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
table.striped tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpXLWy)**